# Where can I find methods to evaluate products?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, products

I found it was slightly difficult to find resources that discussed methods for evaluating products, like $\Pi_{n=0}^ka_n$

Preferably, I want to start with the basics and move through some readings on how to evaluate products.  The most I know about solving these things is proving convergence of infinite products and basic permutation.

Comment: There is no general rule, unless you say something about $a_n$. Notice  that $\log(\prod a_n)=\sum \log a_n.$ This trick is why you can sometimes find  in literature that studying products (especially infinite) is not interesting since the product can be always transformed to summation.

Comment: @iiivooo ah, ok...